# Oracle developer tools for visual studio 2017: Generate ALTER statements instead of DROP/CREATE

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Can Oracle Schema Compare automatically generate ALTER statement for changes in tables instead of generating combination of DROP/CREATE statements?

Comment: It seems that your question is related to some GUI tool. Which one?

Comment: Sorry, i changed the title and tags now. I'am using ODT in Visual Studio.

Comment: @kaushikNayak that's not what that option means

Comment: @thatjeffsmith : Oops..is it? Sorry for spreading wrong info on your product. Hope u won't sue me ..:-)

Comment: @KaushikNayak do you have any $$$? Just kidding, and no offense :)